# Mostrar una lista de elementos proveniente de una vista a un modal en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Supongamos que tengo una lista de elementos en una vista:

```
<% Dim valor As New List(Of Integer)
For i As Integer = 0 To 5%>    
<%valor.Add(i)%>
<% Next%>
```

Los envio a una modal usando data de esta forma:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_noticia_editar" data-valores='<%:valor%>'  data-noticiaid='<%: item.IdNoticia%>' data-titulo='<%: item.TituloNoticia%>' data-descripcion='<%: item.DescripcionNoticia%>' class="noticia_edit">Editar</a>
```

Y cuando se abre el modal, me aparecen datos en donde lo hago de esta forma:

```
    $('.noticia_edit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        NoticiaID = $(this).data('noticiaid');
        Titulo = $(this).data('titulo');
        Descripcion = $(this).data('descripcion');
        valores = $(this).data('valores');


        $("#modal_noticia_editar input[name=noticiaid]").val(NoticiaID);
        $("#modal_noticia_editar input[name=titulo]").val(Titulo);
        $("#modal_noticia_editar input[id=Descripcion_edit]").val(Descripcion);
        $("#modal_noticia_editar input[id=foto_multi]").val(valores);

    });
```

En esta línea

```
 $("#modal_noticia_editar input[id=foto_multi]").val();
```

al `val`, debo pasarle la lista “valores”.

Para esto necesito recorrer la lista y quisiera saber cómo enviarle los elementos de lista valores con **jquery** o **javascript** al val  `input[id=foto_multi]")` para que los elementos de esta lista se muestren.

Comment: for (var i in valores){
   mostrar i;
}

como colocaria algo asi dentro del val();???

Comment: estoy tratando de hacer algo asi:
for (var i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
                $("#modal_noticia_editar input[id=foto_multi]").val(valores[i]);
                
            }

Comment: que tipo de control html es foto_multi, es en select ? porque si se trata de un textbox solo va a poder asignar un unico valor

Comment: se trata de un input,  lo que tendría que hacer seria concatenar...el hecho que no puedo recorrer la lista, me aparece el caracter "]" (sin comillas) como resultado.

Comment: lo que no me queda claro es como queda representado un array que defines en .net cuando lo asignas usando data-valores='<%:valor%>' quizas no deberias asignar a este un array de int, sino un string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ver de usar

```
<% Dim items As New List(Of String)
   For i As Integer = 0 To 5    
      items.Add(i.ToString())
   Next
   Dim valor As String = String.Join(",", items)
%>
```

entonces cuando uses el  data-valores='<%:valor%>' estarias pasando estos separados por coma, en el val() se mostrarian directo

Comment: Excelente Leandro una vez has acertado, pero quiero hacer otra pregunta. En vez de string, como sería en el caso de cuando es binario

Actualmente se muestra las fotos asi:

<% For Each img In item.FOTO%>
                                            <img alt="" src='<%: Url.Action("FotoNoticias", "Noticias", New With {.id = img.IdFoto})%>' height="30" width="30" />
                                       <%  Next%>

pero para almacenarlo en una variable y pasarlo de la misma forma que me indicaste, como sería??

Comment: No vas a poder trabajar binario de forma directa, salvo que conviertas este a base64, entonces con un formato de cadena si podrias trabajarlo. Quizas el action en lugar de ser un Url.Action, podria ser un Html.Action() y devolver un string con el binario en base64  http://librosweb.es/libro/css_avanzado/capitulo_6.html